# ASP.NET MVC 4 and Ninject InRequestScope with RavenDb IDocumentSession in embedded HttpServer mode

Tags: ninject, ravendb, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having some problems with Ninject's `InRequestScope` extension. It's looks like I'm getting new instances of the `IDocumentSession` within the same request. I'm running RavenDb as an embedded HttpServer with the ASP.NET MVC 4 beta. I have a bootstrapper class that looks like this:

```
public static class ApplicationBootstrapper
{
    private static IKernel _kernel;

private static readonly IDocumentStore DocumentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
{
    DataDirectory  = @"App_Data\RavenDb",
    UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true

}.Initialize();

public static void Initialize()
{
    DocumentStore.Conventions.IdentityPartsSeparator = "-";

    _kernel = new StandardKernel();

    _kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
    _kernel.Bind<IDocumentStore>().ToConstant(DocumentStore);

    _kernel.Bind<IDocumentSession>().ToMethod(x =>
    {
        var store = x.Kernel.Get<IDocumentStore>();
        return store.OpenSession();
    }).InRequestScope();
}

public static IKernel Kernel
{
    get { return _kernel; }
}
```

}

I tried settings the scope to `InSingeltonScope`. In that scenario I indeed get the same `IDocumentSession` but that of course is not what I want. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InRequestScope requires one of the Web Extensions. In your case you should install and use Ninject.MVC3 instead of an own Bootstrapper.